# Cómo ejecutar un script en Google App que abra un destino en una carpeta en Google Drive desde un botón en mi barra de herramientas sheet?

Tags: script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-drive

Quería consultar si hay alguna manera de abrir y/o acceder a una carpeta y/o la ubicación de la misma de Google drive por medio de un botón que tengo creado en la barra de herramientas en mi planilla de googlesheet. Investigue todas la maneras y buscado info y no logro que ocurra. Se puede crear, extraer, etc pero simplemente quiero tildar el botón (Abrir carpeta) y que se abra la pestaña del navegador en la carpeta destino en Google Drive. He probado todos los script que he investigado y no logro la acción. He revisado las herramientas de google developer y no encuentro la herramienta específica para la acción que requiero. Agradecería mucho sugerencias.